# Higher order derivatives using Lagrange's primes notation

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In mathematics, the symbol(s) for the derivative of a function using Lagrange's primes notation is nice.  This is because it doesn't look like other symbols in the expression.

Higher order derivatives are commonly denoted with a superscript arabic number in parentheses.  This is not so nice, especially when a mathematical expression already has arabic numbers in the coefficient, subscript, and index.

*Is there a proper way to represent higher order derivatives in Lagrange's primes notation using prime (and possibly backprime) symbols?*

---

This is what I had been using but it doesn't look quite right:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \[y', y^{\prime\prime}, y^{\prime\prime\prime}, 
    {y^{\prime\backprime\prime}}, {y^{\backprime\prime}}, 
    {y^{\backprime\prime\prime}}, {y^{\backprime\prime\prime\prime}}, 
    {y^{\backprime\prime\prime\prime\prime}},\dots\]

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Primes 1-8]

Comment: @BenediktBauer `\backprime` is (not only) defined by `amssymb`.

Comment: _What_ doesn't look “quite right”? What is your question? Why `\backprime`? [Lagrange's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_notation#Lagrange.27s_notation) doesn't use back primes. A superscripted number (roman or parenthesized arabic) is mostly used for derivates greater than three. For example: `y^{(4)}`

Comment: The superscripted number /\/ only looks a little bit like a roman four,

Comment: @UnkleRhaukus Is there any reference to the notation you're proposing? I feel it's very ambiguous; somebody uses Roman numerals for higher order derivatives, but it's not clearer than `$f^{(4)}$` as mostly used nowadays.

Comment: @UnkleRhaukus and how would you do the Roman `X` for 10?

Comment: i dont want the notation to be corrupted by switching to arabic numerals in the superscript, or by switching fonts

Answer (score 10):

```
  y^{\prime\prime}
```

is the normal rendering for multiple primes, but it can be more easily entered by using the input

```
y''
```

In math mode `'` has a special definition that a run of adjacent `'` turns itself into `^{\prime...}` with as many `\prime` in the superscript as there were `'` in the original source.

However as others have said in comments your input looks suspiciously as if intended to be roman numerals

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$ y' \quad y'' \quad y''' $

$
y^\mathrm{\romannumeral 1} \quad
y^\mathrm{\romannumeral 2} \quad
y^\mathrm{\romannumeral 3} \quad
y^\mathrm{\romannumeral 4} \quad
y^\mathrm{\romannumeral 5}
$
\end{document}
```

---

Wikipedia [suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange.27s_notation) That the notation you want is primes for the first three, then Roman numerals so perhaps:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$ y' \quad y'' \quad y''' $

$
y^\textrm{\romannumeral 1} \quad
y^\textrm{\romannumeral 2} \quad
y^\textrm{\romannumeral 3} \quad
y^\textrm{\romannumeral 4} \quad
y^\textrm{\romannumeral 5}
$

\newcommand\lagrangeprime[1]{^{%
\ifcase#1 \or\prime\or\prime\prime\or\prime\prime\prime\else\mathrm{\romannumeral #1}\fi}}

$
y\lagrangeprime{1}\quad
y\lagrangeprime{2}\quad
y\lagrangeprime{3}\quad
y\lagrangeprime{4}\quad
y\lagrangeprime{5}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\textrm`, the roman numerals are typeset in `textstyle`, making them look rather large in their superscript position. More seriously, if the expression is typeset in an environment where the font shape is in italics (say, inside the statement of a `theorem`), the roman numerals will be typeset in italics as well. To get the sizing and upright-shape issues solved, it may be better to set `...\mathrm{\scriptsize\romannumeral #1}` or -- using the `\text` command of the `amsmath` package -- `...\text{\upshape\romannumeral #1}`.

Comment: @Mico oops add amsmath then they won't be, I will regenerate the image

Comment: done `\textrm` picks up `\text` so gets the correct size just by loading amsmath, the markup doesn't need to change apart from that)

Comment: Even with the `amsmath` package loaded, `\textrm` will still generate *italic roman numerals* if the expression occurs inside an italics environment (such as inside the body of a `theorem` environment). Inserting an `\upshape` directive guards against this possibility.

Comment: @Mico you are right of course:(  Why don't I just use `\mathrm` and avoid the complication

Answer (score 4):

#### Input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %  new commands %
\newcommand \bprime {\backprime\hspace{-.11em}      }   %  backstroke
\newcommand \xprime {\prime\hspace{-.25em}\backprime}   %  cross
\begin{document}
$$
y',
y^{\prime\prime},
y^{\prime\prime\prime}, 
y^{\prime\bprime\prime},
y^{\bprime\prime},
y^{\bprime\prime\prime},
y^{\bprime\prime\prime\prime},
y^{\bprime\prime\prime\prime\prime},
y^{\prime\xprime},
y^{\xprime},
y^{\xprime\prime}
\dots
$$
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: why???? would you want to fake Roman numerals out of primes and reverse primes rather than using letters???????

Comment: This notation is completely unintelligible.